# Spring listener transaction with jpa transaction

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

We are trying to perform the following tasks using `@Transactional` annotations (rather than programmatic transaction control) in a Spring Boot app with Spring Kafka and Spring Data.

1. Listen for a new Kafka message from 1 topic via `@KafkaListener`
2. Publish a message to a different Kafka topic via a `KafkaTemplate`
3. Update a JPA Entity [with Hibernate] to an Oracle database via its `JpaRepository`

We need help with the nuances of Kafka+JPA transactions working together.

If we only do steps 2 & 3, this works (all-or-nothing).  But if we start the transaction in the `@KafkaListener` (and its underlying `ContainerFactory` and `TransactionManager`), then the JPA entity update is committed at the `repo.save(entity)` method call rather than when the `@KafkaListener`-annotated method finishes.

We tried the solution documented on Spring's site specifically for this, but that doesn't appear to work.

[https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#ex-jdbc-sync]

What do we need to look for to specifically manage a `@Transaction` that starts when a `@KafkaListener` receives a message [which we want to manually acknowledge] and encompasses both a Kafka message publication and a JPA entity save?

NOTE: We DO NOT want to use deprecated APIs like `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager`